# GVNIX and spatial searchs

Tags: customization, gvnix

I have installed this great development tool and I´m testing how can I use spatial queries or customize other functions.

For example, in the petclinic-geo project create a new map that shows only the owners inside Valencia (area). I think there is no roo commands that can create spatial queries.

In this case, how can I create new custom functions ?, Do I need to remove Roo to do that or either codes can coexist?

Thanks

Comment: what do you want to develop? spatial queries at list view?

Comment: Yes, I would like to create a new filter in the map view that shows only elements near of a point. F.E: If you have the entities Car and GasStation and you select one car in the map I would like to show only the GasStations in 20km around (without routing, only spatial distances between two points). I´m trying to insert the param distance inside of a panel. If you have done something like that, I will apreciate your help ! :) thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry Allen, Currently this feature is not implemented on framework. But, in gvNIX 2.0 roadmap (current in definition), probably, will includes advanced search for geometrical entities.

Anyway, you could make push-in of generated *.aj* files to customize the data request used by map component to fit returned data to your requirements.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @jmvivo I have done some new functios in a new controller and I have done manually some spatial search. I´m fighting with js to display this data in an existing layer...